# Appending span next to clicked link

Tags: jquery

I'm aiming to auto append information to a form based on a users click.

Specifically when a user clicks one of the following 'Book' links:

[image]

I want a information from the hidden span next to it to be auto populated into the form input labeled 'Course':

[image]

I'm planning to use a variable that gets created on click and then appended to the form, however I don't know how to create a variable which targets a sibling span.

JSfiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/cm4Lu2ch/

```js
$('.mailenquiry').click(function(e) {
  var nearestspan = 'How do I target the hidden span next to the clicked on link?'
  $('.custom-contact div:nth-of-type(2) input').val(nearestspan);
});
```

```css
table.table td span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable" class="footable table outerBorder footable-loaded">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="thCol0" data-type="alpha">Date</th>
      <th id="thCol1" data-type="alpha">Module</th>
      <th id="thCol2" data-type="alpha">Price</th>
      <th id="thCol3" data-type="alpha">Venue</th>
      <th>Enquire</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mon 11/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 1</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 1 on Mon 11/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tue 12/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 2</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 2 on Tue 12/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<a id="contact-now"></a>
<form class="custom-contact" action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Course:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: var nearestspan = $(this).next().text();

Comment: Can you explain more or clear your question what you exactly want?

Comment: @sinisake I'd add that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.mailenquiry').click(function(e) {
  var nearestspan = $(this).next().html();
  $('.custom-contact div:nth-of-type(2) input').val(nearestspan);
});
```

```css
table.table td span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable" class="footable table outerBorder footable-loaded">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="thCol0" data-type="alpha">Date</th>
      <th id="thCol1" data-type="alpha">Module</th>
      <th id="thCol2" data-type="alpha">Price</th>
      <th id="thCol3" data-type="alpha">Venue</th>
      <th>Enquire</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mon 11/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 1</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 1 on Mon 11/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tue 12/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 2</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 2 on Tue 12/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<a id="contact-now"></a>
<form class="custom-contact" action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Course:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to do this:

### 1) Go up a level to the parent

Go up to the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the `span`, then get its text and store it in your `nearestspan` variable

```
$('.mailenquiry').click(function(e) {
  var nearestspan = $(this).parent().find('span').text();
  $('.custom-contact div:nth-of-type(2) input').val(nearestspan);
});
```

```js
$('.mailenquiry').click(function(e) {
  var nearestspan = $(this).parent().find('span').text();
  $('.custom-contact div:nth-of-type(2) input').val(nearestspan);
});
```

```css
table.table td span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable" class="footable table outerBorder footable-loaded">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="thCol0" data-type="alpha">Date</th>
      <th id="thCol1" data-type="alpha">Module</th>
      <th id="thCol2" data-type="alpha">Price</th>
      <th id="thCol3" data-type="alpha">Venue</th>
      <th>Enquire</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mon 11/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 1</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 1 on Mon 11/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tue 12/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 2</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 2 on Tue 12/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<a id="contact-now"></a>
<form class="custom-contact" action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Course:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

### 2) Get the next element

you can use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and get the span that way

```
$('.mailenquiry').click(function(e) {
  var nearestspan = $(this).next().text();
  $('.custom-contact div:nth-of-type(2) input').val(nearestspan);
});
```

```js
$('.mailenquiry').click(function(e) {
  var nearestspan = $(this).next().text();
  $('.custom-contact div:nth-of-type(2) input').val(nearestspan);
});
```

```css
table.table td span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="theTable" class="footable table outerBorder footable-loaded">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="thCol0" data-type="alpha">Date</th>
      <th id="thCol1" data-type="alpha">Module</th>
      <th id="thCol2" data-type="alpha">Price</th>
      <th id="thCol3" data-type="alpha">Venue</th>
      <th>Enquire</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mon 11/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 1</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 1 on Mon 11/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tue 12/Dec/17</td>
      <td>Foo 2</td>
      <td>£55 (+VAT &amp; DVSA Upload)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td><a class="mailenquiry" href="#contact-now">Book</a><span>Enquiry about Foo 2 on Tue 12/Dec/17</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<a id="contact-now"></a>
<form class="custom-contact" action="/my-handling-form-page" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name">Course:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```